# Reference file on Android device that was placed via USB

Tags: android, html, macos, filesystems, android-sdcard

I have an html file that I placed on my Android device via USB (Android File Transfer). Android file transfer doesn't show any paths, so I don't know what directory this file is being placed in. I downloaded a file manager app on the device by ZenUI that suggests the file is in "root/sdcard/theFile.html" but referencing it in an app using "file:///root/sdcard/theFile.html" does not work even if all the appropriate Manifest permissions are in place ("file not found").

I am using a Droid Turbo 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably device-dependent. On my Nexus 6 is it

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/file.html
```

(if you placed your file in Downloads).
If you have an SD-Card inside, maybe just trying `emulated/1/...` helps, or just download TotalCommander, navigate to the file and look up the properties of the file (`Location:`) will help you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: TotalCommander is the superior app for sure. Good recommendation and my path ends up being the same on a Droid Turbo 2

Comment: Yeah, on my good old rooted Galaxy Nexus (Samsung) it's the same path, too; i think, all devices with nearly stock android use that path.